# Why is my character flying off in unity 2d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i Click on the play button my Spire flies off into the ceiling of my map.

I have a simple png as a sprite in unity.
I use a tilemap for the level i made which has a TilemapCollider2D and a BoxCollider2D.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDoDu.jpg <- photo of what is happening.

My character has a BoxCollider2D and a Rigidbody2D.
I'm making a side scroller in case that is necessary to know.

The gravity and stuff for the character is normal and so is the mass.

My character(s) should just stay on the ground.

Comment: Try posting some code (the least amount of code possible to show the problem).

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong with the minimal amount of information you provided, but I imagine that your BoxCollider is colliding with the TilemapCollider because it is placed INSIDE the tilemapcollider. This often results in your objects flying off in any direction.

Comment: @Harvey I don't have any code so far.

Comment: @Immorality Is there a solution to this?

Comment: A collider collides with things it touches. Ask yourself this. Should it be possible for a stone to be placed inside a stone? No, it is physically impossible. So is placing a collider inside a collider. It is not possible and forced out of it. So you are either looking to use a trigger or have your colliders setup wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if the grey part of the backroud is the object that has a BoxCollider2D but if it does that that's your issue.

You can't have two BoxColliders overlapping each other otherwise you'll get what your seeing now, one shooting up.

I would suggest removing the BoxCollider2D on the tilemap (if that's possible) and maybe just having a BoxCollider2D on that floor in the picture.

If my answer didn't help or wasn't good enough I would be happy to help you further, just reply to this. :)

Comment: Yes thank you this solved it for me. I had accidentally placed a BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D on the camera and a RigidBody2D on my background, so make sure to check that there isn't an unnecessary BoxCollider2D or RigidBody2D.